# How do you append an array to an array in numpy?

Tags: numpy

How do you append an array to an array in numpy?

My code

```
na = np.append(na , b, axis = 0 )
```

where

```
na = np.array([], dtype=float)
b = [1,2,3,4]
```

output: [1,2,3,4]

Want : [[1,2,3,4]]

Comment: c = np.atleast_2d(b)  plus check the many methods offered in the "Related" section to the right by your question's sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one basic function for joining one array to another, `np.concatenate`, and set that make certain types of concatenation a bit easier (but not faster), `vstack`, `hstack`, `column_stack`, `stack`, `append`.  Read their docs.

A key point is that enough of the dimensions have to match.  Your `na` has shape `(0,)`.  The only thing that matches in shape is itself, and the result is itself.

Here's one way of producing your target from your `b` (which is effectly a `(4,)` array (check `np.array(b).shape`):

```
In [460]: na=np.zeros((0,4),int)
In [461]: np.vstack((na, [1,2,3,4]))
Out[461]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

The result is `(1,4)` a array.  You could have produced that without concatenation

```
In [466]: np.atleast_2d(b)
Out[466]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Study shape and dimensions some more, and play with the basic `concatenate`.  It's tempting to jump into using `append` or one the `stack` without understanding the basic issues.